# Meteor Blaze fetch data and update template

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I have the following logic in my meteor app:

```
   Template.configs.events = {
        'click li': function(e, template) {
           Meteor.call('getMaster', uri, function(err, response) {
           // Template.set(response)
        });
        }
    };
```

After a user clicks on a list, a json object is returned via Ajax. How would I dynamically inject this object into the template? Is there a design pattern?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might handle such return data through the template's reactive variables. using your code, i wrote up a "full" example showing the initialization, setting, and getting of such vars:

```
Template.configs.onCreated(function () {
    this.foo = new ReactiveVar();
    this.bar = new ReactiveVar();
});

Template.configs.helpers({
    foo() {
        return Template.instance().foo.get();
    },

    bar() {
        return Template.instance().bar.get();
    }
});

Template.configs.events({
    'click li': function(e, template) {
        Meteor.call('getMaster', uri, function(err, response) {
            let foo = response.foo;
            let bar = response.bar;

            template.foo.set(foo);
            template.bar.set(bar);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I kinda managed to build the same solution, but with reactive-dict instead of reactive var. I can't figure out the difference though.

Comment: they are similar. the dictionary simply gives a reactive way to keep a bunch of key/value pair objects as a single thing. e.g. maybe you have an unknown number of reactive automobiles; you can't create a reactive var for each because you don't know ahead of time how many you'll have.